# Remote tomcat deployment

Tags: java, deployment, tomcat

I could set up the environment in my local host, But I have no choice like deploying my war file as its shared server, my admin ask me to extract the war file and upload through FTP. Now the problem is I am new to remote server. Please guide me with the remote environment file system and complete directory structure in remote tomcat. And how to use FTP for deployment ?

Answer (score 0):

> Please guide me with the remote environment file system and complete directory structure in remote tomcat

The remote directory structure of a Tomcat install is the same as a local one so you'll very likely have to upload your exploded webapp into `$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps` on the remote machine.

> And how to use FTP for deployment?

Just use any FTP client (no offense but this is more a question for http://superuser.com).

Actually, why don't you ask your admin?